# How to programmatically get the CPU cache line size in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cpu, cpu-cache

I'd like my program to read the cache line size of the CPU it's running on in C++.

I know that this can't be done portably, so I will need a solution for Linux and another for Windows (Solutions for other systems could be useful to others, so post them if you know them).

For Linux I could read the content of /proc/cpuinfo and parse the line beginning with cache_alignment. Maybe there is a better way involving a call to an API.

For Windows I simply have no idea.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Win32, [`GetLogicalProcessorInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx) will give you back a [`SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686694.aspx) which contains a [`CACHE_DESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681979.aspx), which has the information you need.

Comment: Yikes - decoding the array of SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION structures looks like it would be a pain.

Comment: Welcome to the world of systems programming. ;)

Comment: It's not too bad, Michael.  Anyways, getting to grips with it forces you to learn the how CPU topology is arranged, and you may well need to know.

Comment: Woot? No code snippet I can simply copy and paste?!! *cries*

Answer (score 7):

On Linux try the [proccpuinfo library](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/proccpuinfo/), an architecture independent C API for reading /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 5):

Looks like at least SCO unix (http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/man/html.3C/sysconf.3C.html) has `_SC_CACHE_LINE` for sysconf. Perhaps other platforms have something similar?

Answer (score 5):

For x86, the [CPUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction.  A quick google search reveals some [libraries](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cpuid+library) for win32 and c++.  I have used CPUID via inline assembler as well.

Some more info:

- http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/appnote/241618.pdf
- http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/cpuid.php

Comment: could you comment on how you'd use CPUID to get this?

Answer (score 4):

**On Windows**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);
    cout << "Page Size Is: " << systemInfo.dwPageSize;
    getchar();
}
```

**On Linux**

http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpagesize

Comment: After coming back to this I don't believe I answered your question, which was about the cache line size rather then the memory page size correct?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)

I was googling for a page size snippet (working on a project involving memory access) and came here, the dangers of skimming. Please untick my answer, but probably worth leaving it here for future reference.

Comment: Indeed, the question was mistitled with "cache page size".  I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is sample code for those who wonder how to to utilize the function in accepted answer:

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


void ShowCacheSize()
{
    using CPUInfo = SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION;
    DWORD len = 0;
    CPUInfo* buffer = nullptr;

    // Determine required length of a buffer
    if ((GetLogicalProcessorInformation(buffer, &len) == FALSE) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER))
    {
        // Allocate buffer of required size
        buffer = new (std::nothrow) CPUInfo[len]{ };

        if (buffer == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Buffer allocation of " << len << " bytes failed" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (GetLogicalProcessorInformation(buffer, &len) != FALSE)
        {
            const DWORD count = len / sizeof(CPUInfo);
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                // This will be true for multiple returned caches, we need just one
                if (buffer[i].Relationship == RelationCache)
                {
                    std::cout << "Cache line size is: " << buffer[i].Cache.LineSize << " bytes" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }

        delete[] buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `len` is in bytes, shouldn't it be divided by `sizeof(CPUInfo)` before running through the buffer entries?

Comment: @GuillemVS thank you for spotting this, you're correct I've updated my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`NtQuerySystemInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509(VS.85).aspx) from `ntdll.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

If supported by your implementation, C++17 [`std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) would give you an upper bound (and `..._constructive_...` a lower bound), taking into account stuff like hardware prefetch of pairs of lines.

But those are compile-time constants, so can't be correct on all microarchitectures for ISAs which allow different line sizes.  (e.g. older x86 CPUs like Pentium III had 32-byte lines, but all later x86 CPUs have used 64-byte lines, including all x86-64.  It's theoretically possible that some future microarchitecture will use 128-byte lines, but multi-threaded binaries tuned for 64-byte lines are widespread so that's perhaps unlikely for x86.)

For this reason, some current implementations choose not to implement that C++ feature at all.  GCC does implement it, clang doesn't ([*Godbolt*](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxAGkAA6oCoRODB7evgnJqY4CoeFRLLHxgXaYDulCBEzEBJk%2BfuWY9vkMNXUEhZExcQkKtfWN2eVD3WG9Jf3%2BAJS2qF7EyOwc5v5hyN5YANQm/m7hAO772CYaAILnFwD0N2gMg5iqicR7l2EEO7STqQBemAA%2Bl5Eok4oDoosGOgILMTAB2KyXHYonbETAEJYMHaDdAgEAIOroI51IFYQbELxVABuQM%2BcSocUYK0B/0w%2ByRV3hABFrtc7g8ni83tdPt9fngAYDaKgjuDIV5obCEZzUWiMVicQQ8QSiST0YDBQRKTS6YIGUyGCy2Ry%2BTyOPNaJwAKy8PwcLSkVCcNzWaw4xbLTB7Mz%2BHikAiaB3zADWIGdAA4AHT%2BeEANgTGf8zskAE4zAnAk6OJI3VGvZxeAoQBoI1H5nBYDBEChUCxEnQ4uRKGh2534sAFMxEgoEKgCKQsNS8CsAGp4TBHADyYPd4ZotAIcWrEGi5eiYTqAE9OOGD8xiEel9FtJVI9xeL22IIlwxaCePbwsCxDMBxJ/JzwdFTWrADnkqLwt1PXh6WLT0fmiYhjw8LBy2NPAWGg%2BYqAMQd50XFdGGgmRBBEMR2CkEj5CUNRy10Lh9F/FA/UsfQ8GiatIHmVBEnaUCAFol38HZ%2BIAdTEWgRNxfZuWABgvBYiwzE9CoqmcCBXBGPwGJCSZilKPRcjSAQtMMlJjIYHp9P6BjVPaTphk8Jo9Ds6pxisvp4ls8ZTO8roPOmLz5gUQMVgkR0XTLADvQ4HZVEzfi00kHZgGQZAdggY1FRjWYMtwQgSBDMNZl4e8tFmWMQEkLgkzTUMuDDJLnQ0eEuDTXNnX0ThS1ITCzDTWrJEkJK6tzeEEzMHN81Id1PRiqsazrT8G2bCAkF7Dt6DICgIA2/sUAMIwuGa2spxnTB8OXVdiI3LdiB3PcAPPY9iOey9r1vBxiKfRgCFfd9y2/X9/09fBgMcWlQM9cDkEg1Zw1g8sEKQy8UNWT10Mwh9sNwhRLsItdeH4UjRHESjieolR1AA3QzEYoxmMsaw2I4%2BBuN49IBKEkTxNoST%2BOk/xZPkxTlKrVo73SFxoV8oJoQCgyGKM9pZeV9IFZs2wJbUjofKc7JbO1%2Bz3L0zyXL1rJtNsE2ijNrhgtCiiIo4V0ZvLGK4oSpKdi2X8dmOpMNEDvL8CIEV6pKpbyudnq%2BvhJMEwTNr4TMXMNA0VNJA0OnZt4ebbEWsqHVIRsW0WAhEkg7tdrbTa4giVhVnitNEuS32jH951A8D3hMFDkg8DxBiKbIsnpApxQqbokA6aOJDEiwrqXaiubOCXSDK6%2BVAqE9lvvfb4BO%2B7jQMo8PstqKsxI6Liql9jqqu8keF/AzDQEw0Lh340PM3eiysC9rDfSq1Var1UapIZqrV2qdWLP4Feed/5AKXmYeBFYOClXrPMWk90paSCAA%3D)).  It becomes part of the ABI when code uses it in struct layouts, so it's not something compilers can change in future to match future CPUs for the same target.

---

GCC defines both constructive and destructive as `64` x86-64, neglecting the destructive interference that adjacent-line prefetch can cause, e.g. on Intel Sandybridge-family.  It's not nearly as disastrous as false sharing within a cache line in a high-contention case, so you might choose to only use 64-byte alignment to separate objects that different threads will be accessing independently.

- [Should the cache padding size of x86-64 be 128 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126606/should-the-cache-padding-size-of-x86-64-be-128-bytes) - a performance experiment on Skylake showing 500 +- 300 machine clears in an aligned pair of lines, vs. 10M in a single line, vs. near zero in more distant lines.  Machine clears were easier to measure than actual cache misses due to losing access to the line.
- [Understanding std::hardware_destructive_interference_size and std::hardware_constructive_interference_size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680206/understanding-stdhardware-destructive-interference-size-and-stdhardware-cons)