# Programmatically get the cache line size?

Tags: c++, c, caching, operating-system, systems-programming

All platforms welcome, please specify the platform for your answer.

A similar question: [How to programmatically get the CPU cache page size in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/150294)

Comment: FWIW, C++17 will provide a compile-time approximation of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680206/understanding-stdhardware-destructive-interference-size-and-stdhardware-cons

Comment: aside for C/C++, if you won't mind using assembly to get such info, you can take a look (expanding info from negamartin's answer) at SDL2's source code of `SDL_GetCPUCacheLineSize` function, then take a look at `cpuid macro` which has assembly source code for each of processor model. You can take a look at https://imgur.com/a/KP57m6s, or directly peek at the source yourself.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jesstess/797876

Code to get the cache and cache line sizes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [std::hardware_destructive_interference_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) since C++17.
Its defined as:

> Minimum offset between two objects to avoid false sharing. Guaranteed
> to be at least alignof(std::max_align_t)

Answer (score 218):

On Linux (with a reasonably recent kernel), you can get this information out of /sys:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/
```

This directory has a subdirectory for each level of cache.  Each of those directories contains the following files:

```
coherency_line_size
level
number_of_sets
physical_line_partition
shared_cpu_list
shared_cpu_map
size
type
ways_of_associativity
```

This gives you more information about the cache then you'd ever hope to know, including the cacheline size (`coherency_line_size`) as well as what CPUs share this cache.  This is very useful if you are doing multithreaded programming with shared data (you'll get better results if the threads sharing data are also sharing a cache).

Comment: which of the files contains the cache line size? I'm assuming the coherency_line_size? or the physical_line_partition?

Comment: To be sure: this is in Bytes, yes?

Comment: Yes, coherency_line_size is in bytes.

Comment: Could you post sample values of `coherency_line_size` as seen on your machines? For those who don't have Linux at hand.

Comment: @android :   I use fedora-18 x64 machine with core-i5 processor. `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/coherency_line_size` returns `64` in my system. Same for index1,2,3 folders also.

Comment: This technique doesn't work on "Windows Subsystem for Linux", but `sysconf(_SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE)` works on WSL.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK so there is four levels of cache? L0, L1, L2, L3?

Answer (score 191):

On Linux look at sysconf(3).

```
sysconf (_SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE)
```

You can also get it from the command line using getconf:

```
$ getconf LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE
64
```

Comment: simple answers are just the best !

Comment: @warunapww It is in bytes.

Comment: finally! hope more guys see this answer for time saving.

Comment: Is this available on glibc/musl/uClibc? It seems that musl does not have it defined

Answer (score 128):

I have been working on some cache line stuff and needed to write a cross-platform function. I committed it to a github repo at https://github.com/NickStrupat/CacheLineSize, or you can just use the source below. Feel free to do whatever you want with it.

```
#ifndef GET_CACHE_LINE_SIZE_H_INCLUDED
#define GET_CACHE_LINE_SIZE_H_INCLUDED

// Author: Nick Strupat
// Date: October 29, 2010
// Returns the cache line size (in bytes) of the processor, or 0 on failure

#include <stddef.h>
size_t cache_line_size();

#if defined(__APPLE__)

#include <sys/sysctl.h>
size_t cache_line_size() {
    size_t line_size = 0;
    size_t sizeof_line_size = sizeof(line_size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.cachelinesize", &line_size, &sizeof_line_size, 0, 0);
    return line_size;
}

#elif defined(_WIN32)

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
size_t cache_line_size() {
    size_t line_size = 0;
    DWORD buffer_size = 0;
    DWORD i = 0;
    SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION * buffer = 0;

    GetLogicalProcessorInformation(0, &buffer_size);
    buffer = (SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION *)malloc(buffer_size);
    GetLogicalProcessorInformation(&buffer[0], &buffer_size);

    for (i = 0; i != buffer_size / sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION); ++i) {
        if (buffer[i].Relationship == RelationCache && buffer[i].Cache.Level == 1) {
            line_size = buffer[i].Cache.LineSize;
            break;
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    return line_size;
}

#elif defined(linux)

#include <stdio.h>
size_t cache_line_size() {
    FILE * p = 0;
    p = fopen("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index0/coherency_line_size", "r");
    unsigned int i = 0;
    if (p) {
        fscanf(p, "%d", &i);
        fclose(p);
    }
    return i;
}

#else
#error Unrecognized platform
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Might be better to use sysconf(_SC_LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE) for linux.

Comment: @Matt why? Just curious :-).

Answer (score 33):

On x86, you can use the [CPUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction with function 2 to determine various properties of the cache and the TLB.  Parsing the output of function 2 is somewhat complicated, so I'll refer you to section 3.1.3 of the [Intel Processor Identification and the CPUID Instruction](http://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/appnote/241618.pdf) (PDF).

To get this data from C/C++ code, you'll need to use inline assembly, compiler intrinsics, or call an external assembly function to perform the CPUID instruction.

Comment: anyone know about how to do this with other processors with built in cache?

Comment: @ceretullis: Errr... the x86 has built in cache. What "other processors" are you specifically looking for? What you're asking for is platform dependent.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using SDL2 you can use this function:

```
int SDL_GetCPUCacheLineSize(void);
```

Which returns the size of the L1 cache line size, in bytes.

In my x86_64 machine, running this code snippet:

```
printf("CacheLineSize = %d",SDL_GetCPUCacheLineSize());
```

Produces `CacheLineSize = 64`

I know I'm a little late, but just adding information for future visitors.
The SDL documentation currently says the number returned is in KB, but it is actually in bytes.

Comment: Oh my this is really helpful. I'm going to write some game in SDL2 so this is going to be really useful

Answer (score 8):

On the Windows platform:

from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091208-01/?p=15733

> The GetLogicalProcessorInformation
> function will give you characteristics
> of the logical processors in use by
> the system. You can walk the
> SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION
> returned by the function looking for
> entries of type RelationCache. Each
> such entry contains a ProcessorMask
> which tells you which processor(s) the
> entry applies to, and in the
> CACHE_DESCRIPTOR, it tells you what
> type of cache is being described and
> how big the cache line is for that
> cache.

Answer (score 4):

ARMv6 and above has ***`C0`*** or the Cache Type Register. However, its only available in privileged mode.

For example, from [Cortex™-A8 Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344f/DDI0344F_cortex_a8_r2p3_trm.pdf):

> The purpose of the Cache Type Register is to determine the instruction
>   and data cache minimum line length in bytes to enable a range of
>   addresses to be invalidated.
>
> The Cache Type Register is:
>
> - a read-only register
> - accessible in privileged modes only.
>
> The contents of the Cache Type Register depend on the specific
>   implementation.  Figure 3-2 shows the bit arrangement of the Cache
>   Type Register...

---

Don't assume the ARM processor has a cache (apparently, some can be configured without one). The standard way to determine it is via ***`C0`***. From the [ARM ARM](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~waldroj/3d1/arm_arm.pdf), page B6-6:

> From ARMv6, the System Control Coprocessor Cache Type register is the
>   mandated method to define the L1 caches, see Cache Type register on
>   page B6-14. It is also the recommended method for earlier variants of
>   the architecture. In addition, Considerations for additional levels of
>   cache on page B6-12 describes  architecture guidelines for level 2
>   cache support.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to do it programmatically by measuring some timing. Obviously, it won't always be as precise as cpuid and the likes, but it is more portable. ATLAS does it at its configuration stage, you may want to look at it:

http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/