# Finding the cache block size

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cpu-cache

How do I find the cache block size in Ubuntu, programmatically (with C++) or otherwise?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1922249/550514?

Comment: @ChadLaGuardia I would say it is not a duplicate because that question is limited in scope to only C++. Here OP is open to methods outside of the specific language, such as a cli command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find it in `/proc/cpuinfo`; `cache size` for the total size, and `cache_alignment` for the block size.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to fill an `std::vector` or just a plain array with random values, and do something simple, e.g. square each element in a loop. 
Then measure the execution time as a function of the vector length. 
You'll very clearly see a jump in the exec time once your vector does not fit into the cache.