# gcc over-aligned new support (alignas )

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, alignas

I'm having some difficulty finding more information about GCC's aligned-new warning and the gcc -faligned-new option.  Compiling on gcc 7.2.0 (without --std=c++17) and trying to define an aligned struct such as:

```
struct alignas(64) Foo { int x; }
```

Just doing a plain old:

```
Foo * f = new Foo();
```

Gives me the following warning and suggestion:

```
 alignas.cpp:36:25: warning: ‘new’ of type ‘Foo’ with extended alignment 64 [-Waligned-new=]
 Foo * f = new Foo();
                     ^
 alignas.cpp:36:25: note: uses ‘void* operator new(long unsigned int)’, which does not have an alignment parameter
 alignas.cpp:36:25: note: use ‘-faligned-new’ to enable C++17 over-aligned new support
```

I understand that by default `new` will only return memory aligned up to `alignof( std::max_align_t )` ( which is 16 for me ), but what's not clear to me is that if I pass -faligned-new, will gcc now enforce proper new alignment of `new` on my behalf?

Unfortunately the gcc documentation on this is extremely lacking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [gcc's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options):

> -faligned-new
>   Enable support for C++17 `new` of types that require more alignment than `void* ::operator new(std::size_t)` provides. A numeric argument such as -faligned-new=32 can be used to specify how much alignment (in bytes) is provided by that function, but few users will need to override the default of `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

This implies that -faligned-new simply makes the aligned-new features added in [P0035R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html) available without fully enabling C++17 support.

The relevant bits from the C++ standard:
From [cpp.predefined]:

> `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`
>       An integer literal of type `std::size_t` whose value is the alignment guaranteed by a call to `operator new(std::size_t)` or `operator new[](std::size_t)`. [ Note: Larger alignments will be passed to `operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)`, etc. (8.3.4). — end note ]

From [basic.align/3]:

> A *new-extended alignment* is represented by an alignment greater than `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`

And from [expr.new/14]:

> Overload resolution is performed on a function call created by assembling an argument list. The first argument is the amount of space requested, and has type `std::size_t`. If the type of the allocated object has new-extended alignment, the next argument is the type’s alignment, and has type `std::align_val_t`.

---

So in your case with C++17 or -faligned-new, since `Foo` has *new-extended alignment*, `Foo* f = new Foo();` will call `void* operator new(size_t, align_val_t)` to allocate memory and return a pointer to a `Foo` object that is properly aligned on a 64-byte boundary.  Under earlier standards that was not the case.