# Value of -faligned-new in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I had an issue similar to this one 
[gcc over-aligned new support (alignas )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373287/gcc-over-aligned-new-support-alignas)
so I added `-faligned-new` compiler flag.

This fixed a compiler warning. However, when the compiler is run with `--verbose` flag, I get this output https://pastebin.com/X2QZAtSb, in which the most important line is

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'main' '-faligned-new=1' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

GCC manual (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options) states that:

-faligned-new

```
Enable support for C++17 new of types that require more
alignment than void* ::operator new(std::size_t) provides. 
A numeric argument such as -faligned-new=32 can be used to specify how much alignment 
(in bytes) is provided by that function, but few users will need to override 
the default of alignof(std::max_align_t).
```

What does `-faligned-new=1` mean? If I understand correctly, it should be equal to 8 or 16 or something (default of `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t), not 1.

To reproduce compile simple main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";

    return 0;
}
```

using `g++ main.cpp -o main -faligned-new --verbose`

I am compiling the program on GCC 9.3.0, on a Debian system,  `sizeof(max_align_t)` is 32 on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does -faligned-new=1 mean?

Apparently, it means that `-faligned-new` was used without explicit threshold.

As per documentation, the threshold defaults to alignment of `std::max_align_t` in this case.

Comment: It would be reasonable. However I'd expect that value of this flag reported by the compiler will be `sizeof(std::max_align_t)` (in my case: `=32`).  
Have you got any sources that GCC really outputs `some_flag_name=1` if it uses a default value?

Comment: @Dinuirar Your demonstration is one source. You didn't specify a value, and `--verbose` showed 1.