# How to determine SSE prefetch instruction size?

Tags: cpu-architecture, sse, prefetch

I am working with code which contains inline assembly for SSE prefetch instructions. A preprocessor constant determines whether the instructions for 32-, 64- or 128-bye prefetches are used. The application is used on a wide variety of platforms, and so far I have had to investigate in each case which is the best option for the given CPU. I understand that this is the cache line size. Is this information obtainable automatically? It doesn't seem to be explicitly present in /proc/cpuinfo.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794632/programmatically-get-the-cache-line-size) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150294/how-to-programmatically-get-the-cpu-cache-page-size-in-c) one. I think it is clear that - unless you can rely on a OS or library-function - you will want to use the CPUID instruction, but the question then becomes exactly what information you are looking for. - And of course, AMD's and Intel's implementations don't need to agree. This [page](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/cpuid.php) suggests using Cpuid.1.EBX[15:8] (i.e., BH) for finding out on Intel and function 80000005h on AMD. In addition, on Intel, CPUID.2... seems to contain the relevant information, but it looks like a real pain to parse out the desired information.

I think, from what I've read, both AMD and Intel CPUID instructions will support **CPUID.1.EBX[15:8]**, which returns the size of one cache line in QUADWORDs as used by the CLFLUSH instruction (which isn't present on all processors, so I don't know whether you'll always find something there). **So, after executing CPUID.1, you'd have to multiply BH by 8 to get the cache line size in bytes.** This hinges on my implicit assumption (please can anyone say whether it is really valid?) that the definition of one cache line size is always the same for CLFLUSH and PREFETCHh instructions.

Also, Intel's [manuals](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253667.pdf) states that PREFETCHh is only a hint, but that, if it prefetches anything, it will always be a **minimum of 32 bytes**.

EDIT1:
Another useful resource (even if not directly answering your question) for the optimised use of PREFETCHh is Intel's optimisation manual [here](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf).