# Prefetch for Intel Core 2 Duo

Tags: assembly, prefetch, blas

Has anyone had experience using prefetch instructions for the Core 2 Duo processor?

I've been using the (standard?) prefetch set (`prefetchnta`, `prefetcht1`, etc) with success for a series of P4 machines, but when running the code on a Core 2 Duo it seems that the `prefetcht(i)` instructions do nothing, and that the `prefetchnta` instruction is less effective.

My criteria for assessing performance is the timing results for a BLAS 1 vector-vector (axpy) operation, when the vector size is large enough for out-of-cache behaviour.

Have Intel introduced new prefetch instructions?

Comment: The results I'm seeing are as follows.

On a P4: Making use of prefetchnta ensures that the performance is linear with vector size, even when out-of-cache behaviour is reached. Using prefetchnta does not degrade peformance at small sizes.

On a Core2: While prefetchnta is somewhat helpful at large sizes, linear scaling is not preserved. It also degrades performance at small sizes (by about 1/3!).

Is the hardware prefetch getting in the way, or do I need to do something special with prefetchnta on a core 2 duo?

Comment: Software-prefetch needs to be [tuned for the microarchitecture](http://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=132668&curpostid=132676), e.g. how far to prefetch ahead of your loads.  Also, some patterns stop benefiting from SW prefetch in newer uarches that have better HW prefetch

Answer (score 4):

From an [Intel reference document](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf) on Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures, check out page 163 and 77:

> Pentium 4 and Intel Xeon processors
>   based on Intel NetBurst
>   microarchitecture introduced hardware
>   prefetching in addition to software
>   prefetching. The hardware prefetcher
>   operates transparently to fetch data
>   and instruction streams from memory
>   without requiring programmer
>   intervention. Subsequent
>   microarchitectures continue to improve
>   and add features to the hardware
>   prefetching mechanisms. Earlier
>   implementations of hardware
>   prefetching mechanisms focus on
>   prefetching data and instruction from
>   memory to L2; more recent
>   implementations provide additional
>   features to prefetch data from L2 to
>   L1. In Intel NetBurst
>   microarchitecture, the hardware
>   prefetcher can track 8 independent
>   streams.
>
> The Pentium M processor also provides
>   a hardware prefetcher for data. It can
>   track 12 separate streams in the
>   forward direction and 4 streams in the
>   backward direction. The processor’s
>   PREFETCHNTA instruction also fetches
>   64-bytes into the firstlevel data
>   cache without polluting the
>   second-level cache.
>
> Intel Core Solo and Intel Core Duo
>   processors provide more advanced
>   hardware prefetchers for data than
>   Pentium M processors. Key differences
>   are summarized in Table 2-10.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it might be an issue with your code, but consider that the cache line size (which determines the stride size for use with prefetch instructions) may vary between different processors. Therefore, if you use code which is optimised under the assumption of a different cache line size on a CPU where this assumption isn't met, it's bound to deteriorate performance.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380000/how-to-determine-sse-prefetch-instruction-size) here asked how to determine prefetch cache line size.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this once on a tight loop I was trying  to optimize that loaded 4 doubles and did about 15 floating point operations per loop.
I found that to have a positive effect on a core 2 duo, the prefetch needed to be set for at least 16 loops ahead in the code, where for older processors 4 loops ahead was enough.