# Create a MiniDump excluding a range of run-time allocated memories

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, memory-management, minidump

A little bit more info:

I wanted to create a MiniDump file using [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) but excluding a specific range of memories that I've allocated within the modules. These range of memories aren't important for debugging and they are quite large (mostly textures).

I've read the documentation on [MiniDumpCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680358.aspx) functions and looked into the information provided by the [Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680362.aspx) and [Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680363.aspx) structure. MiniDumpCallback input only allows me to decide whether to include the memory range of executable images, and MiniDumpCallback output allows me to decide the range to write for the dump file.

Hence, I wonder if it's possible to create a MiniDump excluding the range of memories that were allocated to some variables that exceeded the size limit.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system allocates memory in pages (typically 4 kb) and it'll only be possible to exclude a whole page. A variable might start in the middle of a page and end in the middle of a page. Other variables may be allocated before and after it. So you can't exclude memory on variable basis.

If a variable is larger than a page and it spans over a complete page, it might be possible to exclude the full pages. However, this will be some work for your callback routine:

Let me assume that it's quite unlikely to have a struct of that large size. So the only possible variable with such a size would be arrays. You could write a method that allocates arrays and keeps track of arrays that span over a complete page. During the callback you could determine the start and end of a page using [GetSystemInfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466518/480982) and then exclude the pages.

Despite the effort implementing this, consider:

- disk space is cheap nowadays. A few MB more or less do not matter. Buying a disk is cheaper than implementing such a behavior.
- crash dumps compress quite well (at least the ones I receive). If you need to send it, ZIP it first.
- if that's still not small enough, you can convert the large dump into a minidump (e.g. open the dump in WinDbg and `.dump` again) and analyze that one first. Only if required, the customer needs to send you the larger file.
- remote debugging. The customer can e.g. open the dump in WinDbg, start a debugging server and you can connect to it.
- For very large allocations, the C++ heap manager will directly call VirtualAlloc() anyway. If the memory region is larger than 512 MB, tools like [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) are already capable of removing the largest allocation (`-mp` switch). (But note that ProcDump will not come into play if you have your own unhandled exception handler)